# why can't read environment variables during unittest?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

using vscode + pytest, while the test cases are written in unittest, for example:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testEnvVar(self):
        account = os.getenv("ACCOUNT")
```

It fails to read `ACCOUNT`. However, `os.getenv("ACCOUNT")` will get right result if it's executed by `python test.py` directly:

```
# test.py
import os
print(os.getenv("ACCOUNT"))
```

that ensure "ACCOUNT" envar is already set.

If executed by `pytest tests/test.py`, the envrionment var cannot be read too, so it's caused by pytest. I know pytest will do some tricks (for example, pytest will capture all console/stderr output), but I don't know what exactly it does to envar. And same as tox(in tox, you have to set `passenv=*`, so the test env can inherit all environment variables from shell where tox lives.

I mean, I totally understand this is trick that all test-related tools could make, I just don't know how to disable it in pytest. So don't suggest that I have forgot set variable, or my code is wrong, etc.

I know how to hack this, by use mock or add .env vars in vscode launch file. However, this will definitely expose account/password in some files/settings. since **account** and **password** are secrets, I don't want to expose them in any files.

I guess this is a very common requirement and pytest should have already hornored that. So why this still happend?

Comment: Obviously the environment variable is not set in your test environment. Without knowing more it is difficult to say why, but pytest itself does not change the environment. Where is the code that sets it?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible code with the steps.

Comment: above is the mimimal reproducible code, at least in my env. To clarify:
1. environment (ACCOUNT) is set, so that simple script can read it, like:
`python -c 'import os;print(os.getenv('ACCOUNT'））`
2. at same time, above unittest will fail to read "ACCOUNT"

Comment: That is strange. So if you do `python -c 'import os;print(os.getenv('ACCOUNT')` just before `python -m pytest` (or whatever you use to invoke `pytest`), it will show that the variable is set, but in the test it is not set?

Comment: it's versy strange, that the issue disappears today...

I had thought that it's related to pytest, coz I know when you start test with tox, you have to set `pass_env=*` if you want to inherit shell's envars, so I though pytest will do the same thing.

I'll monitor this for more days, and get you back @MrBeanBremen. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: confirmed that envars is readable when tests are launched by pytest. Not sure which caused my issue at first place. @MrBeanBremen

Comment: Ok, good to know -  you can probably delete the question in this case.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env. But I don't think you should test the enviroment variables in your unit tests.

Comment: Note that there is `setenv` in the build-in `monkeypatch` fixture to achieve this. Anyway, this does not answer the original question.

Comment: I have checked pytest-env, I don't understand why that answered my question.  I have 'ACCOUNT/PASSWORD' set in my shell envrionemnt, I just want they can be read during unittest, rather than hide by pytest.

Comment: Questions that start with *why* are inviting to debates. There are many levels that you might be refering to. A simple answer is that pytest starts a new process with a clean environment, but I doubt that's any help to you. A deeper answer on why pytest was designed this way (this is only my opinion, I don't know the author's intent) is because reading the enviroment variables is an IO operation (or should be treated as) which worths to be isolated from production and test code as well.
However, on integration tests you may want to setup your tests enviroment and here's the link to the docs:

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html?highlight=environment